# sapply and environments

Tags: r

The loop below modifies `bloc`. Can `sapply()` achieve the same result?

Or in other words, can `sapply()` update variables in the base environment? I tried using `assign()` but without success. Thank you.

```
n <- 100 
fencePosts <- c(17,34) 
bloc <- rep(0,n) 
for (i in 1:length(fencePosts)){   
  bloc[fencePosts[i]:n] = i 
} 
table(bloc)
```

I was thinking of something like the following line, but of course `bloc` is out of scope (although I'm not sure why this doesn't raise a "`bloc` not found" error).

```
zilch <- sapply(1:length(fencePosts),function(i)bloc[fencePosts[i]:n] = i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how kosher it is to the R-perts, but you could do

```
zilch <- sapply(1:length(fencePosts),function(i)bloc[fencePosts[i]:n] <<- i)
```

Comment: I do this sometimes, but only when I can contain the object being assigned to, `bloc` and the `sapply()` call in a little function, which takes `bloc`, etc as an argument and then returns the modified `bloc`

Answer (score 3):

I've not seen `sapply` used this way and even if possible, I'm not sure it's a good idea.  The primary use of `sapply` is for doing the same task on different elements of a list, and then collecting the results in a useful way.  This doesn't match that usage, so I think the code would be difficult to read and maintain, even if it is possible.

In this particular case, why not use `rep`?

```
bloc <- rep(seq_len(length(fencePosts)+1), diff(c(1,fencePosts,n+1))
```

As for why it doesn't work, it does have to do with scoping; one good reference is John Fox's:
http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-scope.pdf.

Comment: Thanks for both the example and the link.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you do not really need any assignment 
inside the loop or inside `sapply`.

```
sapply( 1:n, function(u) sum(u >= fencePosts) )
```